# How to build Arch linux package on Debian

Tags: debian, arch-linux, packages

Long story short - I have to build several Arch linux packages and the only machine available is Debian. Is it possible at all? Usual Arch packaging tools are not available in any Debian repo known to me. Of course I could run Vagrant box on Debian machine but for now let's assume any kind of virtualization is a no-go.

Comment: "...any kind of virtualization is a no-go." I guess in this particular environment asking for Arch machine would have more chance of success than asking for installing Vagrant.

Comment: Maybe try a chroot installation. [Install from existing Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_existing_Linux)

Comment: Why don't you boot a live ArchLinux system to build the package?

Comment: Chrooted installation does not allow for building Arch packages, makepkg can be run only from regular account (non-root). Been there, tried that. And I don't have physical access to the machine.

Comment: You can chroot as a normal user. I can't imagine any reasons why you couldn't install the arch tools into a chroot, chroot into it as a user, and run those tools. The toolbox shouldn't rely on any of the Arch specific stuff.